# Too slow site loading speed

Tags: pagespeed

Our company is a manufacturer of warehouse equipment and mobile loading ramps. Our website https://www.de.av-exim.com was reported to load very slowly, today I installed the image optimization plugin, Website opening speed has been improved a little，but maybe there are some code still needs to be optimized, so could you help me check and optimize it?
Thank you very much!
Best wishes!

Comment: It's not easy to say it in one word.
Can you contact me?

Comment: We can assist.  Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: View profile for contact info.

Comment: If you check for shared vs dedicated server for ausbas.com. From your browser myip.ms  reports you are sharing with 57 live websites using your ip address of 178.254.16.194 - you may wish to consider a dedicated plan with your hosting provider.  We can still help you if requested data is provided for analysis.